# go type conversion - sort 2 slices of different interfaces using shared interface

Tags: sorting, go, type-conversion

The example below contains 2 interfaces `Foo` and `Bar` that both implement the same interface `Timestamper`. It also contains the type `ByTimestamp` that implements [sort.Interface](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface).

As shown in the function `main`, I would like to use the type `ByTimestamp` to sort both a slice of `Foo`s and a slice of `Bar`s. However, the code will not compile because it `cannot convert foos (type []Foo) to type ByTimestamp` and it `cannot convert bars (type []Bar) to type ByTimestamp`.

Is it possible to sort 2 slices of different interfaces that both implement the same interface with a single type that implements `sort.Interface`?

```
package main

import (
    "sort"
)

type Timestamper interface {
    Timestamp() int64
}

type ByTimestamp []Timestamper

func (b ByTimestamp) Len() int {
    return len(b)
}

func (b ByTimestamp) Swap(i, j int) {
    b[i], b[j] = b[j], b[i]
}

func (b ByTimestamp) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return b[i].Timestamp() < b[j].Timestamp()
}

type Foo interface {
    Timestamper
    DoFoo() error
}

type Bar interface {
    Timestamper
    DoBar() error
}

func getFoos() (foos []Foo) {
    // TODO get foos
    return
}

func getBars() (bars []Bar) {
    // TODO get bars
    return
}

func main() {
    foos := getFoos()
    bars := getBars()

    sort.Sort(ByTimestamp(foos))
    sort.Sort(ByTimestamp(bars))
}
```

[The Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IV9wd78Xoje)

Comment: Does it have to be an implementation of sort.Interface?  sort.Slice with type assertions should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to sort different types using one `sort.Interface`.
But not the way you were trying to do it. Current Go specification doesn't allow converting one slice type to another. You have to convert each item.

Here's a helper function that does it using reflection:

```
// ByTimestamp converts a slice of Timestamper into a slice
// that can be sorted by timestamp.
func ByTimestamp(slice interface{}) sort.Interface {
    value := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    length := value.Len()
    b := make(byTimestamp, 0, length)
    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        b = append(b, value.Index(i).Interface().(Timestamper))
    }
    return b
}
```

See the full example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/JbM0gbQRwYh).

And, if you only have a couple of types, then it might make sense to do type-specific conversions instead.